# ObjC iOS11: TextField doesn't show up when becoming first responder in inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder, inputaccessoryview

So I have this code to create my inputAccessoryView when the keyboard shows up:

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 44)];;
self.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UILabel *nrLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 140, 21)];
nrLabel.text = @"Number:";
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nrLabel]];

self.nrTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 140, 28)];
self.nrTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.nrTextField]];

UILabel *amountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 100, 21)];
amountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:amountLabel]];

self.amountTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 100, 28)];
self.amountTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.amountTextField]];

self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
self.toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[self.nrTextField becomeFirstResponder];
return self.toolbar;
```

It works fine as long as I don't tell the nrTextField to become first responder. Ist this somehow illegal to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this UIToolbar was supposed to be an extension to the keyboard, I had to call the becomeFirstResponder at the right time.
So i wrote a keyboardDidShow method and called it via NSNotification. In this method I set the TextField to become first responder.